# xargs: invalid option -- 'o'

Tags: command-line, tty, kubernetes, xargs

I was trying to execute [this command](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/37471#issuecomment-378738512) to fix yet another error (Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file):

```
kubectl get pods -n foobar | grep baz | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -J % kubectl exec -it -n foobar % /bin/bash
```

Which resulted in the following error:

```
xargs: invalid option -- 'o'
```

I was able to execute the command correctly on my Mac Mojave, but not on Ubuntu 16.04.

According to the [xargs website](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html), there should have been a -o option:

> --open-tty
>
> -o
>
> Reopen stdin as /dev/tty in the child process before executing the command, thus allowing that command to be associated to the terminal while xargs reads from a different stream, e.g. from a pipe. This is useful if you want xargs to run an interactive application.
>
> grep -lz PATTERN * | xargs -0o vi

But `man xargs` did not show this option.

The [changelog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/findutils/+changelog) did not mention any change to the flag.

My xargs version on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

```
xargs (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-o` option which you want was added in 2017.  Your version is from 2016.  You need to upgrade.

#### Details

Note the year in your version message:

```
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Now, look at this section from the `findutils` ChangeLog:

```
2017-06-08  Bernhard Voelker  <mail@bernhard-voelker.de>

        xargs: add -o, --open-tty option
        This option is available in the xargs implementation of FreeBSD, NetBSD,
        OpenBSD and in the Apple variant.  Add it for compatibility.
```

#### Workaround

`man xargs` from the 2016 version shows this example for a work-around:

```
xargs sh -c 'emacs "$@" < /dev/tty' emacs
```

This example is for `emacs` but the same idea applies to any other command that you may wish to run.  Like the `-o` option, this approach assures that the command that is  being run has access to a terminal.